Binding SSL certificate to a new site, but after browsing it shows another site certificate
I have several site in my iis. I define sperate sites and assign exact certificate for each site.
But when I browsing, I get one of my site certificate.
I also use require server indication tick for all me sites.
Please let me know what should I do ?
I erase certificates and re add them
Also I create separate sites

You will have to get started from HTTP API, https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/https-binding#ip-based-bindings

Check the certificate that is bound to the site in IIS. You can right-click on the site and choose edit bindings. In there, you should see a binding for port 443 that is associated with an SSL cert.
Besides, you can check if the certificate has been bound to the specific port, please type Netsh HTTP command at the command prompt.
Netsh http show sslcert |findstr 443

